# Shortcode Function not working

Tags: shortcode

I got this code to show my thumbnails images and videos on my blog page, but when i try to use to show the thumbs in another page, it doesnt works.

Function to display images and videos thumbs

```
function show_blog_posts() {
global $post, $blog, $posts;
$first_vid = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<iframe.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_vid = $matches [1] [0];

if ($output == '1') {
    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="';
    echo $first_vid;
    echo '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
} else { ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');?>
```

My shortcode

```
add_shortcode('recent_blog_posts', 'shortcode_recent_blog_posts');

function shortcode_recent_blog_posts($atts) {

        $str = '';
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
        $postslist = get_posts( $args );

        foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
            $str .= '<div id ="article-section-box2" class="span3">';
                            $str .= '<div id= "image1" class="image-arcticle">';     
                            $str .= show_blog_posts($post->ID, '');
                            $str .= '</div>'; 
                            $str .='<p class="article_text">'.excerpt(18).'</p>';
                            $str .='</div>';
        endforeach; 

        return $str;
```

Is there anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: Turn on debugging so you can learn more than "it doesnt work".

Comment: [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: Debugging is informing : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Pabloswebsite\functions.php on line 28 and 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `show_blog_posts` two parameters...

```
$str .= show_blog_posts($post->ID, '');
```

... but you have defined it to accept none...

```
function show_blog_posts() {
```

There seems to be some disconnect between your two blocks of code. I'd suggest actually passing the `$post` object the way that you are trying to.

```
function show_blog_posts($post = NULL) {
    global $blog, $posts;
    if (empty($post)) {
        global $post;
    }
    // the rest of your function
```

No idea what that second parameter is supposed to be.

Comment: I did what u said but keeps "not working" to me yet :( sry for my english

Comment: What changed between when you posted that comment and when you accepted the answer?